# Login link on stackexchange.com is missing styling

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The login link on https://stackexchange.com/ has a bad contrast with the black background:

[image]

Unlike e.g. this site, where it's a button, it has been a plain link [for a while](https://web.archive.org/web/20220101011800/https://stackexchange.com/) but with much better contrast:

[image]

The blue text works fine on a lighter background (i.e. a proper button) like here on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Should this be closed as no longer reproducible, or marked [status-completed]? The stackexchange.com login button looks fine to me now.

Comment: @V2Blast one of your colleagues fixed it less than two weeks ago, please give them my thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed somewhere earlier this month; [this snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20230206185400/https://stackexchange.com/) from February 2023, 6th at 18:54 UTC has the problematic styling but [6-8 hours later](https://web.archive.org/web/20230207001240/https://stackexchange.com/) the link was promoted to a Stacks-styled button:

[image]